# How to handle .toPromise() deprecation with RXJS and Angular 13

Tags: angular, rxjs, apollo-client, angular-promise

Hello I'm trying to figure out how to handle this deprecation on this code

```
const authCtx = (auth: AngularFireAuth) =>
  setContext(async () => {
    const token = await auth.idToken.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
    return {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };
  });
```

I'm taking the jwt token from Firebase and set that token on my  graphQL module when the user is logged in but I got the warning that toPromise is deprecated and it say that I should implement lastValueFrom or firstValueForm so I thint I could be something like this:

```
const authCtx = (auth: AngularFireAuth) =>
  setContext(async () => {
    const token = lastValueFrom(auth.idToken)
    return {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };
  });
```

I'm not pretty sure what is the right sinxtax to update this code

Comment: _The lastValueFrom is almost exactly the same as toPromise() meaning that it will resolve with the last value that has arrived when the Observable completes._
There are examples in the [doc](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise).
So it colud be: `const token = await lastValueFrom(auth.idToken.pipe(take(1)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this with `firstValueFrom`

```ts
const authCtx = (auth: AngularFireAuth) =>
  setContext(() =>
    firstValueFrom(auth.idToken.pipe(
      map(token => ({ headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }}))
    )
  );
```